# Combine IN Operator values with temporary table

Tags: sql, postgresql, temporary, in-operator

Part of my current query is this CASE WHEN statement:

`CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(article_code,1,4) IN     ('Ak42','Ales','AlHe','Artu','Behr','Crea','Digi','Egos','Emu_','Fend','Fen2','GiSt',Icon','InMa','Korg','Lin6','Li6S','MAud','MGtr','Mack','Nova','Focu','NoLa','NoLM','Relo','Tasc','TC_E','Vest','Xona','Xpre','Zoom','SndC','LtGn') 
THEN 'X' ELSE 'Y' END AS lup`

This is not only awkward to read/format it also has a fundamental flaw, namely that the list of values contained in the `IN` Operator is not static but dynamic. As there is no such lookup_table contained in the database and this is unlikely to change, I was wondering if it is possible to create a temp table which looks like this...:

**AC**

- InMa
- Relo
- Zoom
- etc..

... and then use those values in column AC as values for the `IN` operator, such as:

```
CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(article_code,1,4) IN (temp_table) THEN 'X' ELSE 'Y' END AS lup
```

It is even possible to use the `IN` operator in such a fashion?
If that isn't possible, maybe there is another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  The syntax is:

```
(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(article_code,1,4) IN (select article_code from temp_table) THEN 'X'
      ELSE 'Y'
 END) AS lup
```

For best performance, create the table with `article_code` as the primary key or create an index on it.